# Battery management system - voltage at BAT pin

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, bms

I am working on a BMS with a [BQ76940](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76940.pdf). I have prepared a circuit with the help of the Typical Application Schematic from the data sheet. I have connected 9 cells to start with.

When I measure the voltage between PIN 20 (BAT) and PIN 3 (VSS), I am getting a voltage of 33 V. Is this normal? I have not interfaced a microcontroller yet.

[image]

I am using Lithium Ion cells. The maximum voltage to BAT with respect to VSS should be 36 V. What if I connect 15 cells? The voltage at BAT pin would be over 55 V.

Comment: it depends on your battery technology (Lithium Ion or LiFePo4). Assuming Lithium Ion, your 9 cells (presumably in series) have a charge of 33/9 = 3.67 V each (on average), which is a perfectly normal storage charge. My question is, what did you expect and what are you concerned about? Have you measured the individual cells?

Comment: I am using Lithium Ion cells. The maximum voltage to BAT with respect to VSS should be 36V. What if I connect 15 cells? The voltage at BAT pin would be over 55V.

Comment: Maybe you should add this information to the question to clarify it. Also, see my answer. There is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The data sheet for the BQ76940 (page 10), shows the maximum voltages as voltage differences between cell input pins (and thus only part of the full battery pack voltage): *(BAT–VC10x), (VC10x–VC5x), (VC5x–VSS)* and not *BAT - Vss* (which would be the full pack voltage).

[image]

These (partial battery pack voltages) should not exceed 36V, and they do not.

For a 15 Cell pack you would expect a, fully charged, maximum voltage of 15 x 4.2V = 63V, but only 5 x 4.2 = 21V between any of the pins mentioned in the data sheet.

Comment: When I measure the voltage across PACK+ and PACK-, I get a reading of approximately 5V. Is it normal? I have not connected the microcontroller yet.